ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after setting up django with gunicorn and nginx
I am developing some website, until now I was using python manage.py runserver to access it, it was running fine. I decided to make it production-ready and set up gunicorn, and I am getting redirect loop. Considering that it works fine under runserver, I guess there is a problem with nginx configuration, but what am I doing wrong?
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
        location /static/ {
                alias /path/to/project;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/project/run/app.sock;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 1000000;    }
}

Tried few different nginx configuration but to no avail. Even disabled all views and urls in django and it does not make any difference, so it has to be nginx, right?
Gunicorn is running fine without any errors too.
And I am not running any redirects in my django project at all, not in views and not in urls. It's a simple website.
